# Wordpress not showing pages!

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I've installed wordpress locally, and created a few pages, but when I try to refer them, they do now show up. Instead I get a 404 error. when I try to open

```
http://localhost/mySite/About
```

page, it tries to open the file

```
D:\mySite\About
```

, which doesn't exist. Any problem with permalinks or htaccess file?? My site is at D:\mySite and I'm creating a new theme. I've created the page.php file so that it shows my page but no luck.

Comment: Too little info. But most likely .htaccess. Please delete your question here, and repost on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: also check your permalink settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using wamp, the problem was that, by default, mode-rewrite was not being loaded. My mistake, now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working on Windows you need to work with the web.config instead even with PHP because that's how IIS works.

More information here:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/466/enabling-pretty-permalinks-in-wordpress/